# List order after duplicate filtering

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to teach myself functional language thinking and have written a procedure that takes a list and returns a list with duplicates filtered out. This works, but the output list is sorted in the order in which the *last* instance of each duplicate item is found in the input list.

```
(define (inlist L n)
  (cond
   ((null? L) #f)
   ((= (car L) n) #t)
   (else (inlist (cdr L) n))
   ))

(define (uniquelist L)
 (cond
   ((null? L) '())
   ((= 1 (length L)) L)
   ((inlist (cdr L) (car L)) (uniquelist (cdr L)))
   (else (cons (car L) (uniquelist (cdr L))))
   ))
```

So..

```
(uniquelist '(1 1 2 3)) => (1 2 3)
```

...but...

```
(uniquelist '(1 2 3 1)) => (2 3 1)
```

Is there a simple alternative that maintains the order of the *first* instance of each duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem would be to use Racket's built-in [`remove-duplicates`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29) procedure. But of course, you want to implement the solution from scratch. Here's a way using idiomatic Racket, and notice that we can use [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29) (another built-in function) in place of `inlist`:

```
(define (uniquelist L)
  (let loop ([lst (reverse L)] [acc empty])
    (cond [(empty? lst)
           acc]
          [(member (first lst) (rest lst))
           (loop (rest lst) acc)]
          [else
           (loop (rest lst) (cons (first lst) acc))])))
```

Or we can write the same procedure using standard Scheme, as shown in SICP:

```
(define (uniquelist L)
  (let loop ((lst (reverse L)) (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? lst)
           acc)
          ((member (car lst) (cdr lst))
           (loop (cdr lst) acc))
          (else
           (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))))))
```

The above makes use of a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html?q=db#%28part._.Named_let%29) for iteration, and shows how to write a [tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) implementation. It works as expected:

```
(uniquelist '(1 1 2 3))
=> '(1 2 3)

(uniquelist '(1 2 3 1))
=> '(1 2 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar - that explains it nicely